# What is this Lab equipment?

Tags: equipment

I want to know the name of this equipment with a sealed graduated tube and the purpose it's being used.

[image]

I went through all the results of Google, but I was unable to find this exact equipment. I believe someone here should know this very well.

Comment: What's the piece you're holding?

Comment: @Beerhunter What do you mean? I'm also asking what's that :)

Comment: The glass piece, just out of shot, being directly held

Comment: Oh, it's the base stand of the equipment. Just a circular glass base which helps you to keep it on a table, you know. Nothing is hidden in the pic. Suppose my hand is the table, it's like now it's kept on the table :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This lab equipment is called 'Fermentation Tube'.

[image]

If you want to see how an experiment is carried out with this equipment, please watch the video below.

[Mark Garcia: Lab Protocol - Fermentation in Yeast (Unit 9 Respiration); YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uN9POjK_iBE)

Comment: We use these in one of our Nursing Chemistry labs on carbohydrates.  They show that not all carbohydrates will ferment.

Answer (score 6):

The piece is a type of *[eudiometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eudiometer)* also called a *gas measuring tube*.  The graduations are for measuring gas collected and the bulb is used to hold liquid to assist in filling the tube with liquid.